# Sync iCal subscribed calendars

Tags: calendar, web-services

In Google Calendar, I can add a calendar a link to an iCal file. However, unlike calendars listed under "My calendars", this new calendar (listed under Other calendars) won't show up on other calendar apps with my Google Calendar, such as Windows 10 Calendar, or iOS Calendar, or Samsung Calendar. What I have to do then is add the subscribed .ics file to each and every one of those clients manually. Is there an alternative to Google Calendar that I can use that will sync these subscribed calendars to my calendar clients?

The price should ideally be less than $15 and not a subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Outlook.com calendar](https://outlook.live.com/calendar/) does a fine job of syncing subscribed calendars, at least for the default Windows 10 Mail and iOS Calendar. For Android, you can use [One Calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=biz.codespark.xcalendarapp), which supports subscribed calendars from both Google Calendar and Outlook.com calendar.

[Business Calendar 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.bizcal) shows subscribed calendars from Google Calendar, but can't sync with Outlook.com. Samsung Calendar doesn't support subscribed calendars from Google Calendar and can't sync with Outlook.com