# Is there a service which will make google calendar more frequently pull updates from the urls it's subscribed to?

Tags: google-calendar

When importing from a URL, Google Calendar only updates ~2x a day.  Most platforms will update in minutes:

https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/1096466/url-calendar-not-updating?hl=en

I did find one user asking how to leave Google Calendar behind as to get around this issue:

[Sync iCal subscribed calendars](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/71927/sync-ical-subscribed-calendars)

I also checked into the API and found that it's not too difficult to write a program that regularly tells Google Calendar to fetch updates.  But I don't want to deal with maintaining my own server just to get the calendar to update regularly.

**Is there a service which will regularly ping Google Calendar and tell it to pull updates from the calendars it is subscribed to?**